# Convert all zeros to ones which are between ones in numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

Consider a numpy array

```
arr = numpy.array([[1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
[1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1],
[0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]])
```

I want convert all zeroes to ones between ones

output should be

```
[[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
 [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
 [0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]
```

How can I achieve this? Is there any numpy function to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one approach using [`np.maximum.accumulate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.4/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.accumulate.html) by using it on a column-flipped version and without it and simply getting the intersection of them -

```
def fill_gaps(arr):
    ma = np.maximum.accumulate
    return ma(arr[:,::-1],axis=1)[:,::-1] & ma(arr,axis=1)
```

Sample runs -

```
# Sample #1
In [27]: print arr
[[1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1]
 [0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]

In [28]: print fill_gaps(arr)
[[1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]

# Sample #2
In [42]: print arr
[[1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]

In [43]: print fill_gaps(arr)
[[1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
```

To fill for an array with `0s` and some other value say `255s`, here's a modification -

```
def fill_gaps(arr, value=1):
    ma = np.maximum.accumulate
    mask = arr==value
    mask_filled = ma(mask[:,::-1],axis=1)[:,::-1] & ma(mask,axis=1)
    return np.where(mask_filled,value,0)
```

Sample run -

```
In [69]: print arr
[[255   0 255   0 255   0 255   0   0   0   0 255   0   0   0   0   0   0
    0 255   0   0 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255]
 [  0   0   0 255   0 255   0 255   0 255   0 255   0 255   0 255   0 255
    0 255   0 255   0 255   0 255   0 255   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0   0 255   0 255 255 255 255 255   0   0   0 255 255 255
    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]]

In [70]: print fill_gaps(arr, 255)
[[255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
  255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255]
 [  0   0   0 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
  255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0   0 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]]
```

Comment: What if I have 255s instead of 0s?

Comment: @BharathShetty So, you would have an array of only `1s` and `255s`?

Comment: shouldn't that work with `np.where(~fill_gaps(arr), 1, 255)`?

Comment: @Divakar I have an array of only 0s and 255s

Comment: @BharathShetty Check out the edits, as suggested by Nico, we needed `np.where` there.